# How setup iframe with Youtube link?

Tags: javascript, angular, youtube, angular5

It downloads a file instead of play. I totally don't understand why, because I'm doing by a tutorial.

Component:

```
public infoPage: InfoPage;
public trustUrl: SafeResourceUrl;
constructor(
    public oAuthService: OAuthService,
    private dataService: DataService,
    public router: Router,
    public route: ActivatedRoute,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        if (params['id']) {
            this.dataService.get<InfoPage>('api/infopages/' + params['id'])
                .subscribe(infoPage => {
                    this.updateVideoUrl(infoPage);
                    this.infoPage = infoPage;
                });
        }
    });
}
public ngOnInit() {
    this.infoPage = {};
}

public updateVideoUrl(infoPage: InfoPage) {
    if (infoPage == null || infoPage.youtubeVideoUrl == null)
        return "";
    this.trustUrl =
        this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(infoPage.youtubeVideoUrl.replace("watch?v=", "v/"));
}
```

and view

```
 <iframe width="560" height="315" class="e2e-iframe-trusted-src" [src]="trustUrl" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Where you are removing the watch?v= from the URL, that could be what is causing it to download instead.

Comment: Thank. I have to change url. But I have to replace to 'embed/' instead of 'v/'

Comment: That makes sense, so it is working now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple component to build the iframe HTML for you

https://github.com/SamirHodzic/ngx-embed-video

A little hint is that the generated string must be used in a `div` with `innerHTML` attribute bind. Something like this:

`<div [innerHTML]="youtubeEmbedPlayer"></div>`

In your .ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EmbedVideoService } from 'ngx-embed-video';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: '<div [innerHtml]="iframe_html"></div>',
})
export class AppComponent {
  youtubeEmbedPlayer: any;
  youtubeUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHhcHTlGtRs";

  constructor(
    private embedService: EmbedVideoService
  ) {
    this.youtubeEmbedPlayer = this.embedService.embed(youtubeUrl);
  )
}
```

This component - ngx-embed-video - will manipulate the url from youtube/vimeo/dailymotion, to generate the correct iframe setup. Like magic..